# RewriteRule - Give access to folder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I use RewriteRule to shorten the links from ?s=xxx to /xxx - but I have some problems that I cant access files in some folders. To help with that I have make an exception in the rule as:

```
RewriteRule ^(inv.*) $1 [L]
```

This because I have .pdf files in the folder "inv".

But the problem is that I also have some sites that is called /invitation. The problem is that this link gives 404 error.

If I remowe the line above, the /invitation works - but then I get 404 error on the /inv/xx.pdf.

How can I change the RewriteRule that makes both works.

Thanks.

This is my entire .htaccess file:

```
DirectoryIndex i.php index.php index.html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^robots.txt - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(inv.*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /?s=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(nyhet)/([^/]+)/?$ /?s=$1&n=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /?s=$1_$2 [NC,L]
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.domain.com/404
ErrorDocument 403 http://www.domain.com/404
```

Answer (score 0):

disable reportory contenu by

```
Options All -Indexes
```

then fix rules of files

```
<Files ~ "([.][^][*])^.*\.">
order allow,deny
deny from all
satisfy all
</Files>
```